# What does BIPUSH 0x3d mean in IJVM

Tags: assembly

I am new to assembly code and just had a question about the following code, mainly regarding the BIPUSH lines. I know that BIPUSH pushes the variable onto the stack.  But what does the 0x2b mean? I am guessing that it has something to do with that variables place in the register. 
If 0x2b is the first place in the register, then why is 0x3d the next space available in the register? Lastly, what would be the next available space following 0x3d?

```
    ISTORE x        // store return value in x
BIPUSH 0x2b     // print “-“
OUT
LDC_W OBJREF
INVOKEVIRTUAL getnum
ISTORE y        // store return value in y
BIPUSH 0x3d     // print “+”
OUT
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operand to `BIPUSH` is an immediate that's going to be pushed on the stack, ie. it's not a variable. Your comments seem to be wrong because 0x2b is the ascii code of `+` and 0x3d is the ascii code of `=`. The `ILOAD` instruction can be used to push a local variable onto the stack.

Comment: `0x2b` is `+` in ASCII, so either the first comment is wrong as well, or a non-ASCII encoding is used.